# Beginning shell scripting

Tags: shell, shell-script

I want to learn Unix shell scripting. how to start?

Comment: Wow, have you done any research at all?

Comment: Please ask real, targeted questions. You already have asked the same question in [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969305/beginning-shell-scripting) and it was closed.

Comment: "Very welcome", guys, new user with good name Alex Sean, mb our future has gone, with the result of -4 reputation, that guarantees no return...

Comment: command language systematic, kernigan ritchi pike book "unix good environment" (noone whom I know haven't dealt with end-chapter tasks(problems or how to say english задания), . As knowledge depends on every command it's very importang to know the file structure basics, and specifically on your system

Answer (score 4):

The [BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) is well written and accurate.

Answer (score 1):

In the interest of avoiding another question ;) here is a good tutorial that I find good and helped me in a few areas.

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/

Of course you could just have googled that :)

Comment: The infamous "advanced" Bash scripting guide will teach you to write bugs, not scripts. Don't use it unless you know how to filter out the crap.